# Adding a ExactTarget calendar event using SOAP or REST API

Tags: rest-api, marketing-cloud, soap-api

Is it possible to add a custom calendar event to the Calendar pane in the Marketing Cloud interface using the ExactTarget API? I'm writing an app which does "stuff" and I'd like the app to add a custom event to the calendar.

I've had a look at both the REST and SOAP API and I'm not sure if there is a method to achieve this. Please can someone confirm?

Comment: Any update on this?
As this was asked in april '14, API's have been updated after that

Comment: There have been a number of new REST API methods added since April 2014, but there is still no API method to create, read or edit calendar events.

Comment: Hi Eliot, is this still the current state? [The docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/associateAssetToCampaign.htm) say that one can associate an asset of type `calendar_event` to a campaign via API, but I cant find that type of asset anywhere else in the docs. Do you (or anybody else) have any new information on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct - currently there is not a public route available for adding items to the calendar.